# Parameter for setting up parallel processing in Oracle Thin JDBC Connect String

Tags: oracle, performance, parallel-processing

i would like to know if there is a connect param, that i can use in JDBC Thin Oracle Connection URL,
to tell the Oracle DB that i want to use Parallelism in processing the queries.

The Application, that should be use this parameter generates Statements during runtime and fires them against the Database, so i can't update or optimize them. In nearly every query i run in timeouts and the User on the other side gets an error message.

If i fire the generated Statements and send them with /* parallel */ Hint with the SQL Developer, i have a much better performance.

Maybe someone has a hint, that i can achive a better performance.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is such a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a logon trigger to force parallel execution of all query statements in the session for which parallelization is possible. This would override any default parallelism property on individual objects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER1.LOGON_TRG
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY 4';
END;
/
```

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/parameters-parallel-exec.html#GUID-FEDED00B-57AF-4BB0-ACDB-73F43B71754A

Comment: `ENABLE PARALLEL QUERY` will open parallelism onl yif th eunderlining object have set `DOP`, better for this purpose is to used `FORCE  PARALLEL QUERY` -  pls update

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```xml
<property>
    <name>jdbc.session.property.alter_session_parallel.1</name> 
    <value>force.query.1</value>
</property>
```